# How to get CentOS Kernel Source in order to install VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtualbox

**TL;DR:** The running kernel version was older than the kernel source that VirtualBox found when trying to install. There is no need to build the source yourself; final resolution was to actually remove the newer version of kernel source, and install the matching version found in `uname -r`, all through `yum`.

History:

When trying to install VirtualBox-4.2 on a new CentOS server I was getting the following:

> Your kernel headers for kernel 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 cannot be found at
>   /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64/build or /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64/source.

So in following the instructions on CentOS [I Need the Kernel Source](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source#head-a8dae925eec15786df9f6f8c918eff16bf67be0d) I tried getting the source and I now have `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6` with 2 folders: `linux-x` and `vanilla-x`.

I tried installing VirtualBox again but it errored about not finding kernel source so I also had to set up these symlinks:

> /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64/build -> /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64
>   /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 -> /home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6

But when trying to install VirtualBox now I get errors about needing to run make:

**/var/log/vbox-install.log**

```
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.18/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxhost-4.2.18

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make KERNELRELEASE=2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.2.18/build...(bad exit status: 2)
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64/build modules
test -e include/linux/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (            \
        echo;                                                           \
        echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";               \
        echo "         include/linux/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";      \
        echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
        echo;                                                           \
        /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*

  WARNING: Symbol version dump /home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include -Iinclude  -I/home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include -include include/linux/autoconf.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Os -m64 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fno-stack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm -fconserve-stack -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -I/lib/modules/2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(SUPDrv_linux)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxdrv)"  -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c
In file included from /home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd.h:5,
                 from include/linux/unistd.h:7,
                 from /home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include/asm/seccomp_64.h:4,
                 from /home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include/asm/seccomp.h:4,
                 from include/linux/seccomp.h:8,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:80,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:92,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:32:
/home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h:719:29: error: asm/asm-offsets.h: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [vboxdrv] Error 2
```

1) I'm not sure exactly where I am supposed to run these make commands
 2) I tried running the commands in each BUILD/kernel-x/vanilla & linux folders but I got errors when doing it in the vanilla folder:

```
[dirt@loki kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6]$ cd linux-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64/
[dirt@loki linux-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64]$ make oldconfig && make prepare
scripts/kconfig/conf -o arch/x86/Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/x86/Kconfig
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-x86
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
[dirt@loki linux-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64]$ cd ../vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/
[dirt@loki vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6]$ make oldconfig && make prepare
scripts/kconfig/conf -o arch/x86/Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/x86/Kconfig
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-x86
  CC      arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets.s
In file included from include/linux/fs.h:424,
                 from include/trace/events/kmem.h:8,
                 from include/linux/kmemtrace.h:12,
                 from include/linux/slub_def.h:13,
                 from include/linux/slab.h:162,
                 from include/linux/percpu.h:5,
                 from /home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include/asm/local.h:4,
                 from include/linux/module.h:20,
                 from include/linux/crypto.h:21,
                 from arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets_64.c:8,
                 from arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets.c:4:
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:11: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'local_t'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h: In function 'percpu_down_read':
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:19: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'locked'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:21: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'mtx'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:23: error: implicit declaration of function 'local_inc'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:23: error: implicit declaration of function 'this_cpu_ptr'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:23: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'counters'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:25: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'mtx'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:29: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'counters'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h: In function 'percpu_up_read':
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:49: error: implicit declaration of function 'local_dec'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:49: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'counters'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h: At top level:
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:53: error: expected ')' before '*' token
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h: In function 'percpu_down_write':
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:66: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'mtx'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:67: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'locked'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:69: error: implicit declaration of function '__percpu_count'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:69: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'counters'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h: In function 'percpu_up_write':
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:76: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'locked'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:77: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'mtx'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h: In function 'percpu_init_rwsem':
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:83: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'counters'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:83: error: implicit declaration of function 'alloc_percpu'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:83: error: 'local_t' undeclared (first use in this function)
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:83: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:83: error: for each function it appears in.)
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:84: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'counters'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:87: error: implicit declaration of function 'local_set'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:87: error: implicit declaration of function 'per_cpu_ptr'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:87: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'counters'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:88: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'locked'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:89: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'mtx'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h: In function 'percpu_free_rwsem':
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:95: error: implicit declaration of function 'free_percpu'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:95: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'counters'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:96: error: 'struct percpu_rw_semaphore' has no member named 'counters'
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
In file included from /home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include/asm/local.h:4,
                 from include/linux/module.h:20,
                 from include/linux/crypto.h:21,
                 from arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets_64.c:8,
                 from arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets.c:4:
include/linux/percpu.h: At top level:
include/linux/percpu.h:168: error: conflicting types for 'free_percpu'
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:95: note: previous implicit declaration of 'free_percpu' was here
In file included from include/linux/module.h:20,
                 from include/linux/crypto.h:21,
                 from arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets_64.c:8,
                 from arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets.c:4:
/home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include/asm/local.h:19: error: conflicting types for 'local_inc'
/home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include/asm/local.h:19: error: static declaration of 'local_inc' follows non-static declaration
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:23: note: previous implicit declaration of 'local_inc' was here
/home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include/asm/local.h:25: error: conflicting types for 'local_dec'
/home/dirt/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/vanilla-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6/arch/x86/include/asm/local.h:25: error: static declaration of 'local_dec' follows non-static declaration
include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:49: note: previous implicit declaration of 'local_dec' was here
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

Comment: So what was in the logs?

Comment: The end of the log is likely to be more useful

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry, was hitting the content limit. I added more of the log. I figured the beginning stating that the version variables not being there would explain the errors in the rest of the file.

Comment: I edited the question to be more precise/clear with logs. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No thanks to the down-voters, I was able to figure this out and make the process much easier, no need to manually build the source.

The problem (for me) was that the newer versions of the kernel/headers were installed and I had to remove them before I could install the older version I needed to match my running kernel:

First remove 18.1 (I found that the 'headers' are the only ones you need to remove, the 'devel' can have the newer and older version side by side):

```
sudo yum remove kernel-headers-2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64
```

Now install 6.2:

```
sudo yum install kernel-headers-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64
sudo yum install kernel-devel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64
```

Now when installing VirtualBox everything is good.

Comment: I downvoted your question because you failed to even bother to read the information provided in your terminal or the logfile but I still tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.

```
     include/linux/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
     Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
```

I'd start with that.

Comment: I ran those commands in  `~/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-x/vanilla-x` and `~/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-x/linux-x`. The one in vanilla gave errors. Am I not doing this in the right place? Am I not getting/building the source correctly?

Comment: I edited the question to be more precise/clear with logs. Thanks for any help.